# How to resolve React Native package error issue and run the app in windows system

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-windows

I'm completely new into react native. Trying to run an existing react native app after cloning it into my system => [weather-app](https://github.com/subhojitGWL1993/subhojits-weather-app.git) in windows but getting the below package error while trying to run the project in my windows system after doing npm start:

```
$ npm start

> Weather@0.1.0 start C:\Users\subho\Desktop\subhojits-weather-app
> react-native-scripts start

7:22:54 PM: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
Warning: 'react' peer dependency missing. Run `npm ls` in C:\Users\subho\Desktop\subhojits-weather-app to see full warning.

If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in C:\Users\subho\Desktop\subhojits-weather-app and restart.
Starting React Native packager...
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\subho\Desktop\subhojits-weather-app\node_modules (110ms)

Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class
```

I'm also unaware about what are the other process I need to follow to successfully run the app in my windows system. It would be nice if step by step process can be mentioned in the answer as well. Any help would be appreciated regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your node version, to 12.9.1 it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this `npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite` and then try

I see you have a regular expression error which is causing this problem. Slash on windows and other OS differed and cause this problem.

The issue you see could be because of this issue. https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/4698